# Android - Listview .remove() function is not working as expected

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that is able to delete a specific image via onLongClick, but it isn't working so far. When testing, the dialog appears If i want to delete or not, i press Yes/Ok and the toast appears saying Item deleted, however the item is still there.

**UPDATED** ( I got the remove and delete function working thanks to user1140237)

**UPDATED MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
private String[] FilePathStrings;
private String[] FileNameStrings;
private File[] listFile;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yearbook);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"/CapturyGallery");

    // Check for SD Card
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"/CapturyGallery");
        // Create a new folder if no folder named CapturyGallery exist
        file.mkdirs();
    }


    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        listFile = file.listFiles();
        // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
        FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
        // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
        FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
        {
            //Get the path image file
            FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
            // Get the name image file
            FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(listFile);

     final ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Yearbook.this, FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);
     ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListingView);
     lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

     final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(FilePathStrings));





    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            //Deletes item
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(Yearbook.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + FileNameStrings[position]);
            final int positionToRemove = position;
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    File file = new File(list.get(positionToRemove));
                    if (file.delete()) {
                        list.remove(position);
                        ((CustomAdapter) listAdapter).updateMyData(FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), FileNameStrings[position] + " deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            });
            adb.show();
            return true;
        }

    });


}
```

**CUSTOMADAPTER**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] filepath;
private String[] filename;


private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
    activity = a;
    filepath = fpath;
    filename = fname;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


}
public void updateMyData(String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
    filepath = fpath;
    filename = fname;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filepath.length;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

class MyViewHolder {
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView timestamp;
    TextView myName;
    TextView myHeader;
    MyViewHolder(View v) {
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.PicView);
        timestamp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        myName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myName);
        myHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);

    }
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(vi);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]),100,100);


    holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    //PicImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    holder.myImage.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    //Set Title
    holder.myName.setText(filename[position]);

    ExifInterface intf = null;
    try {
        intf = new ExifInterface(filepath[position]);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(intf != null) {
        String dateString = intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
        holder.timestamp.setText("Date Taken: " + dateString.toString());
    }


    return vi;
}
```

And so my last problem is, whenever i remove something from my listview it crashed. However, the file was indeed removed. Im not sure what is the error because i tested it on my mobile phone

Comment: you need to update display data list in your `CustomAdapter` class & than call `notifyDataSetChanged()` . or please post 'CustomAdapter'  class code

Comment: updated CustomAdapter class please take a look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update list data in your custom adapter too. after removing than call notifydatasetchanged

Keep below method in you customadapter to udpate list data & after that call it in longpress

```
public void updateMyData(String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
            filepath = fpath;
            filename = fname;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

You need to call this from longPress

```
 list.remove(position);
                    ((CustomAdapter )listAdapter).updateMyData( FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings); /// here in your case you need to define both array global sorry not time to clean up your code
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), FileNameStrings[position] +" deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**UPDATED**

To remove file from the mentioned dir & updating listview you need to delete file from that location first and than you need to update listview

```
 File file = new File(list.get(position));
            if (file.delete()) {// this will required permission in Manifest for Write_EXTERNAL_STORATE
                // if file is deleted from SD CARD
                list.remove(position);
                ((CustomAdapter )listAdapter).updateMyData( FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings); /// here in your case you need to define both array global sorry not time to clean up your code
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), FileNameStrings[position] + " deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

***CustomAdapter ***

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<String> filepath;
        private ArrayList<String> filename;
        private JSONArray jListData;
        private int size = 0;

        public CustomAdapter(Activity a, JSONArray jListData) {
            activity = a;
            this.jListData = jListData;
            if (filepath != null)
                size = jListData.length();


        }

        public void updateMyData(JSONArray jListData) {
            this.jListData = jListData;
            size = jListData.length();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return size;

        }

        public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
            try {
                return (JSONObject) jListData.get(position);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        class MyViewHolder {
            ImageView myImage;
            TextView timestamp;
            TextView myName;
            TextView myHeader;

            MyViewHolder(View v) {
                myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.PicView);
                timestamp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
                myName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myName);
                myHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);

            }
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            MyViewHolder holder = null;
            try {
                if (vi == null) {
                    vi = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
                    holder = new MyViewHolder(vi);
                    vi.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (MyViewHolder) vi.getTag();
                }
                JSONObject rowObject = this.jListData.getJSONObject(position);
                Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rowObject.optString("filename")), 100, 100);


                holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                //PicImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                holder.myImage.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

                //Set Title
                holder.myName.setText(rowObject.optString("filename"));

                ExifInterface intf = null;
                try {
                    intf = new ExifInterface(rowObject.optString("filepath"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (intf != null) {
                    String dateString = intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
                    holder.timestamp.setText("Date Taken: " + dateString.toString());
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }


            return vi;
        }
    }
```

***ACTIVITY***

```
private JSONArray jArrayFileData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_yearbook);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/CapturyGallery");

        // Check for SD Card
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/CapturyGallery");
            // Create a new folder if no folder named CapturyGallery exist
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        jArrayFileData = new JSONArray();
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
            FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
            // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
            FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
                //Get the path image file
//                FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                // Get the name image file
//                FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
                jObject.put("filepath", listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                jObject.put("filename", listFile[i].getName());
                jArrayFileData.put(jObject);
            }
        }
//        Arrays.sort(listFile);

        final ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Yearbook.this, jArrayFileData);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListingView);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

//        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(FilePathStrings));


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                //Deletes item
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Yearbook.this);
                adb.setTitle("Delete?");
                adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + FileNameStrings[position]);
                final int positionToRemove = position;
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        try {
                            File file = new File(list.get(positionToRemove));
                            if (file.delete()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jArrayFileData.getJSONObject(position).optString("filename") + " deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                jArrayFileData.remove(position);
    //                            list.remove(position);
                                ((CustomAdapter) listAdapter).updateMyData(jArrayFileData);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        }


                    }
                });
                adb.show();
                return true;
            }

        });


    }
```

Comment: hmm thats weird, it still did not delete the file despite having no errors. I was searching thru various answers and i am curious if what i was doing is wrong on this part. final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(FilePathStrings)); . Since i declared my String[] into a Final ArrayList in order to use the function .remove(); does this code have any impact on not deleting the file?

Comment: It seems rather complicated for something simple. Alright so i confirmed the deletion works now, thanks.  But please pardon me as i am to bother you for 1 last thing. whenever i delete something my entire app crashed. But when i went back in i can confirm the file has been deleted and no longer appears in my listview. So i could say the notifyDataSetChanged(); did not worked as planned.

Comment: @NewBoy whats the eception are you getting ? or can you please post that code .. i mean update in you question your latest code after updating my changes

Comment: Yes its correct and working, appreciate that you changed my code for the better. Huge thanks and upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arraylist<String>` for fpath and fname in your code: Then to delete data from your listview. 
Use this:

```
fpath.remove(index_toDelete);
fpath.remove(index_toDelete);
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```